# How to get shopify stores products

Tags: python

I am looking for a way I could get the best selling page data that appears on any shopify website, eg. https://exampleshopify.com/collections/all?sort-by=best-selling. This URL returns a view which is differently structured for every different shopify store. I want to have a generic code/idea that could crawl this data or could get it from API for every store.

**NOTE: Make sure to replace `exampleshopify.com` with any other available shopify store website.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know python, But if you add .json to the URL you'll get a json object which I think you can process it easily using python.

```
https://exampleshopify.com/collections/all/products.json?sort-by=best-selling
```

Comment: that breaks the route. Page not available.

Comment: make sure you add .json before the url parameters

Comment: try this one i just edited your example on the fly
`https://exampleshopify.com/collections/all/products.json?sort-by=best-selling`